# py2exe missing Module

Tags: py2exe

my py2exe setup file. I have a module that i put together, its located in project/lib/execution_timer.py(c)

i need to include that file in my build. no matter what i have tried it can not find that module. if i manually copy the file into the dist dir it works fine. but how can i automatically include this.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=['file.py'],
    zipfile=None,
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                    'includes': 'execution_timer'
            }    
    }
)
```

Comment: is your setup.py in project/lib/setup.py? and you are importing execution_timer inside file.py? file.py is in the same folder? if yes to all questions, py2exe should automatically find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to:

- specify the **extension of the module** you want to include
- make sure that this error is not due to a [**relative import**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34632845/relative-import-error-with-py2exe/34772426#34772426). It might be enough to specify also the path, if the extension of the module is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    from distutils.core import setup
    import py2exe

```
setup(
    console=['file.py'],
    zipfile=None,
    packages=['lib'],
    package_dir={'lib':'lib'},   
    }
)
```