# Relative import error with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, relative-import

I was trying to generate an executable for a simple Python script. My setup.py code looks like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["script.py"])
```

However, I am getting the error shown in the screenshot. Is there something I could try to fix this? I am using Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Need more information, for example, your project file structures. But try adding py2exe path to your PYTHONPATH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that in your **mf3.py** you are [importing beyond the top level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175534/relative-imports-in-python).

Let's suppose that your project structure is as follows:

```
folder/
main.py
mod/
    __init__.py
    components/
        __init__.py
        expander.py
        language_id.py
    utilities/
        __init__.py
        functions.py
```

**First make sure that**

> > main.py refers to the subpackages as:
>
> ```
> from mod.components.expander import *
> from mod.utilities.functions import *
> ```
>
> expander.py and language_id.py have access to functions.py with:
>
> `from ..utilities.functions import *`

**Add options to your setup.py**

You can also use more [py2exe options](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ListOfOptions) in order that you are importing all the modules and the packages required by your project. E.g.

```
# setup.py
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=["script.py"],
      options={
              "py2exe":{
                    "optimize": 2,
                    "includes": ["mf1.py", "mf2.py", "mf3.py"], # List of all the modules you want to import
                    "packages": ["package1"] # List of the package you want to make sure that will be imported
               }
       }
    )
```

In this way you can force the import of the missing script of your project