# Python Gtk3 executable

Tags: python, gtk

I started using [GTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK) 3 with Python. How could I make an executable Windows file from my GTK 3 Python source using *[PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/)*, [cx_Freeze](https://marcelotduarte.github.io/cx_Freeze/) or py2exe?

I tried a lot of answers from Stack Overflow and many other web pages, but none worked.

I tried to make it with PyInstaller (I think it could be the easiest way) and my source code looks like:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Button Demo")
        self.set_border_width(10)

        hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.add(hbox)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Click Me")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_click_me_clicked)
        hbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("_Open")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_open_clicked)
        hbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

        button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("_Close")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_close_clicked)
        hbox.pack_start(button, True, True, 0)

    def on_click_me_clicked(self, button):
        print("\"Click me\" button was clicked")

    def on_open_clicked(self, button):
        print("\"Open\" button was clicked")

    def on_close_clicked(self, button):
        print("Closing application")
        Gtk.main_quit()

win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\python34\lib\gi\__init__.py", line 102, in require_version
    raise ValueError('Namespace %s not available' % namespace)
ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available
gtk returned -1
```

What shall I do with this or how can I make an executable in py2exe or cx_Freeze?

Comment: You should use cx_Freeze as py2exe is for python 2 I'll post an example of the layout and I'm going to want you to run it and then run the .exe file and tell me if there any error messages and I will help you fix them.

Comment: I used for a long time py2exe on Python 3.4. The error is in your required version, not in py2exe..

Comment: ValueError: Namespace Gtk not available which is raised by the line 2 of your <module>

Comment: The OP got that error when using pyinstaller not py2exe.

Comment: Ah ok! Then try to use **py2exe**. You can use as a [reference this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34772426/5687152) I gave to a question

Comment: @mabe02 The thing I hate about python to exe conversion questions is that they never really get noticed and most of the time you have to figure it out yourself, or if you answer a question your answer doesn't get any attention and the OP never comes back to acknowledge your answer most of the time.

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax sometimes the documentation of such libraries doesn't contain enough examples, but sometimes people don't read it at all :)

Answer (score 3):

### Install cx_Freeze

You should just be able to do `pip install cx_Freeze` on Windows. Or you could go to their official website [cx_Freeze](https://marcelotduarte.github.io/cx_Freeze/).

---

### Create a *setup.py* file in the same folder as your program.

#### File *setup.py*

```py
import cx_Freeze

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("file.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="WhatEverYouWantToNameIt",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":["gi"]}},
    executables = executables
)
```

Open command prompt in the file location of your program. On Windows, you should just have to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd><left-click</kbd> the folder and click open command window here. Once that opens up, type `python setup.py build`. If you get an error stating that Python is not in your path, then give the full path. For example, on Windows, with Python 3.4, you would do:

```
C:/Python34/python setup.py build
```

If you're on a Mac, then you would do:

```
python setup.py bdist_dmg
```

---

Once it's done, come back and tell me if it works. If it doesn't work, just give me the error message, and I'll fix the problem. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not the original poster but I'm getting the same error when trying to package my application for windows xp. I tried your solution, it didn't work at first because cx_freeze will throw an error if you don't specify a version number. After fixing that, I got the same error I was getting with pyinstaller "namespace gtk not available".